# Activate a maven profile when a system property is not available

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I'm trying to activate a maven profile when the system property GIT_COMMIT is not present when building my project. My profile in pom looks like below. Note the ! symbol in front of my env.GIT_COMMIT variable.

```
  <profile>
     <id>ci-buildno</id>
     <activation>
        <property>
           <name>!env.GIT_COMMIT</name>
        </property>
     </activation>
     <properties>
        <buildText>SNAPSHOT</buildText>
     </properties>
  </profile>
```

When I build the project I get the error shown below.

```
  $ mvn clean install
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
  [WARNING] The POM for com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-
  plugin:jar:0.0.24 is missing, no dependency information available
  [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
  [ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.day.jcr.vault:content-
  package-maven-plugin:0.0.24 or one of its dependencies could not be 
  resolved: Failure to find com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-
  plugin:jar:0.0.24 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in 
  the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update 
  interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @
  [ERROR] Unknown packaging: content-package @ Test-Project:test-
  testcommons.ui.apps:[unknown-version], D:\testing\ui.apps\pom.xml, line 
  28, column 15
```

if I were to remove the ! and then build it works okay and the build is successful. I could have put the inverse condition (After removing the !) and change my buildText to what I want incase the property is present but I'm wondering why this won't work! I read through the maven docs http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
and found that the ! works on system property. GIT_COMMIT, i thought is a system property but unsure why this does not work.

Can I pls get some help here? If it will help to paste the entire pom.xml, pls let me know.

Thanks!!

Comment: Documentation does not mention prefix `env.` at quick glance. Did you try without?

Comment: Is that reference to the env variable GIT_COMMIT used somewhere else too? what are you doing with buildText in the build? Are you setting a version? It seems there is no default or "else" for your case as the version of some artifact is missing: Test-Project:test-testcommons.ui.apps:[unknown-version]

Comment: You seemed to be having different issue that the activated profile cause it looks like some downloads are not working for the content-package-mave-plugin jar ???

Comment: Here's what worked for me!  my project has 4 modules and a parent module. I originally had the changes (given above in my original post) in my parent pom. That's when I was getting this weird error. When I move the same thing to one of my modules pom the build no longer fails. I still have the ! Operator infact the exact thing that I posted above. Still unsure why it wouldn't work when in  parent pom but works in a module's pom but atleast it works when placed in module's pom.

Comment: @pirho yea I tried but it doesn't seem to work without the env. either

Comment: @khmarbaise that's what I thought too. But if I just remove the ! Symbol from before the end.GIT_COMMIT the build succeeds which makes me think that the issue is with the ! Operator.

Comment: Is there another profile in the POM hierarchy that includes `activeByDefault`? In my experience developers often read that as "always active" but what it really means is "active only if no other profile is active." If there is a profile like this, it's possible that enabling the 'ci-buildno' profile caused another profile to be deactivated and cause the issues observed.